# Am I meant to commit yarn's `.pnp.js` file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, yarnpkg

Yarn includes an optional ["Plug'n'Play" feature](https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/pnp) which moves `node_modules` out of the project directory. In doing so it creates a `.pnp.js` file with references to various dependency paths on the hard drive.

The file is auto-generated, is several thousand lines long, and appears to reference paths *specific to the machine* that ran `yarn install`.

Is `.pnp.js` meant to be commited with the rest of the code? I can't seem to find any information about this despite the file appearing to be useless to commit. What is conisdered best practice and why?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I found [this comment by Arcanis](https://github.com/yarnpkg/berry/issues/454#issuecomment-530312089) (the lead maintainer of Yarn) on an issue asking about what to include in a `.gitignore`. It may answer your question:

> - `.yarn/plugins` and `.yarn/releases` contain the Yarn releases used in the current repository (as defined by `yarn set version`). You will want to keep them versioned (this prevents potential issues if, say, two engineers use different Yarn versions with different features).
> - `.yarn/unplugged` should likely always be ignored, since it may contain native builds
> - `.yarn/build-state.yml` should likely be ignored as well, as it contains the build infos
>
>   - If for some reason you version `unplugged`, it may make sense to keep `build-state` as well
> - `.yarn/cache` may be ignored, but you'll need to run `yarn install` to regenerate it
>
>   - Versioning it unlocks what we call [Zero-Installs](https://next.yarnpkg.com/features/zero-installs) - it's optional, though
> - `.pnp.js` (and potentially `.pnp.data.json`) are in the same boat as the cache. Add it to your repository if you keep your cache in your repository, and ignore it otherwise.
> - `yarn.lock` should always be stored within your repository ([even if you develop a library](https://twitter.com/arcanis/status/1164229994165559299))
>
> So to summarize:
>
> **If you're using Zero-Installs:**
>
> ```
> .yarn/unplugged
> .yarn/build-state.yml
> ```
>
> **If you're not using Zero-Installs:**
>
> ```
> .yarn/*
> !.yarn/releases
> !.yarn/plugins
> .pnp.*
> ```

Comment: what's a zero-install

Comment: zero install is a yarn 2/berry feature that allows you to clone & run

Comment: Here are the [official .gitignore recommendations](https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/qa#which-files-should-be-gitignored)

Answer (score 6):

As one of the commenters noted, [the official .gitignore recommendations are here](https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/qa#which-files-should-be-gitignored), along with excellent commentary. The only critique I have is in the way they showed it there, I think they should have combined the common ways into one, and then separated the special cases for zero-install vs not. Here then is how I have it. But again, note that article, as some of these (e.g. `.yarn/sdk`) are optionally added or not.

```
# ------- yarn -------
# see excellent notes at: https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/qa#which-files-should-be-gitignored
# Also: `yarn.lock` and `.yarnrc.yml` (or it's older counterpart .yarnrc) "should always be stored in your repo"
.yarn/*
!.yarn/patches
!.yarn/plugins
!.yarn/releases
!.yarn/sdks
!.yarn/versions

## --> ADD if using zero-install, otherwise do NOT:
#!.yarn/cache

## --> ELSE ADD if NOT using yarn's zero-install:
.pnp.*

# ------- end yarn -------
```